# File.Move all files of type

Tags: c#

The following code is working, but I need to amend it so it moves *all* .txt files instead of just the test.txt file.

```
File.Move(@"C:\Desktop\test\test.txt", @"C:\Desktop\test\old\test.txt");
```

How can I amend it to do this?

It's moving them from the test folder to the test\old subfolder

Comment: Get the directory.files collection from the directory you want to move then just do `.Where(x => x.EndsWith(".txt"));`

Answer (score 1):

whith this you can get all files with path and after that with for you can copy all files to your path

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
```